# Замена int main() на bool main()

Tags: c++, функции, переменные, main

Вот интересно стало, можно ли вместо `int main()` писать `bool main()`?
Это повлияет на производительность? Ну и правда, зачем возвращать `int`(4 байта), если можно `bool`(1 байт)
. Все равно return 0, а больше и не надо возвращать))

Comment: даже если ты на калькуляторе, то это не повлияет на производительность

Comment: Зачем возвращать один байт, когда можно вернуть один бит? Ведь bool и есть один бит.

Comment: Это определяется конкретной реализацией. Если компилятор не возражает, то можно, если возражает, то нельзя. И как по вашему это должно повлиять на производительность? Вы миллиарды раз перезапускаете своё приложение? Даже если и влияет (очень сомневаюсь) - это экономия на спичках. И ещё: никто не запрещает `bool` быть, например, 8-байтным.

Comment: Это какой-то рекордно экстремальный случай преждевременной оптимизации. Как вы думаете, сколько раз  за много часов работы вашей программы будет происходить возврат из функции main? Кроме того, вы в курсе, что этот код возврата обычно передается системе и та требует 4 байта?

Comment: Вы правы, друзья, это жлобство!

Comment: @user7860670 а откуда инфа про 4 байта? По идее `int` может и двухбайтовым быть.

Comment: Используйте сразу `void` - ещё больше сэкономите :-D